# We count number of days in January in which there was no car accidents on specific road

Tags: probability

We count number of days in January in which there was no car accidents on specific road. Probability that at least 1 accident happened during the single day is $\frac{2}{3}$.

**a)** What's the avarage numbers of days without an accident.

**b)** What is standard deviation from that number?

**c)** Which distribution does this random variable have?

**Answers:**

**a)** No accident =
1-$\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}=p$

$E(X)=np$

$D^{2}X=npq$

$n=31$

$E(X)=\frac{31}{3}$

Avarage number of days without accident = $10.33$

**b)**
Deviation= $\sqrt{npq}=\sqrt{31\cdot \frac{1}{3}} \cdot \frac{2}{3}=\sqrt{\frac{62}{9}}$

**c)**
Binomial distribution

Is this done correctly?

Comment: You don't take into account the number of days in January, which is certainly relevant to the problem.

Comment: @lulu Ops, I am still green. Should I use it like this? $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{31}$?

Comment: Think about it. We figure one day in three is accident free, so $\frac {31}3$.

Comment: @lulu Could you check main post? I edited it with my new answer

Comment: I don't understand how you got $\sigma$.  It should just be $\sqrt {31\times \frac 13\times \frac 23}=\sqrt {\frac {62}9}$.

Comment: @lulu ops sorry, I did $31 \cdot 31 \cdot 2$

Comment: The other parts are right.